# How to add payment form fields in stripe, angular5

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I have the payment form with just the, the card number, cvc, expiry date and zip.
I want to add fields like billing name, billing address. So customers can add this more info.

How can I address this?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.card = this.pmt.elements.create('card');
    this.card.mount(this.cardElement.nativeElement);
}
```

I tried something like this....It's not the way as it didn't work.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.card = this.pmt.elements.create('card', {
      billing_name: true
    });
   this.card.mount(this.cardElement.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: What is this.cardElement, that you reference on line 2 of ngAfterViewInit? Can you post the entire component file (ts and html)?

Comment: it's a element in html..```<div id="card-element" #cardElement></div>```

Comment: did you use @ViewChild() to get the reference to the #cardElement?

Comment: Yes, I did.```  @ViewChild('cardElement') cardElement: ElementRef;```

Answer (score 0):

It is very helpful for me.

You should Follow [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/) Documentation and it's repositories for add extra form fields in stripe payment.